# Do I need root to use NewzDroid?

Tags: rooting

I would like to use NewzDroid for usenet, but I'm not sure if I need root for it to work.

Comment: Why are you using it? What's the problem with Google Groups? I'm just curious..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Their website](http://www.newzdroid.com/) doesn't say that you need to be rooted to use it.  Just need a NZB file and a Usenet account.

Comment: How can I import an nzb into newzdroid?

Comment: @James http://www.newzdroid.com/tipsAndTricks.html